# Qt5 - how to use Free? Asking for money

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I need to use Qt5 till i release my final version, my client wont pay until he see the whole application is stable and not having any issue. But Qt5 is asking money before even i get a client.

In Ubuntu how to use Qt5 for free? Is there no way to use Qt5 for free in Linux? (pay only if i have to sell my .PKG, .DMG, .EXE, .SH) ?

Comment: `Qt5` will ask you certain questions to determine if to charge you, so I suggested you select the personal option so you can get it for  free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it for free select the following options at the various steps:

1. Step 1: `select In house development` or `Select opensource`
2. Step 2: `distribute :select No`
3. Step 3: `able to comply withe the licenses :select Yes`
4. Step 4: You will be shown a box to download it for free.

It's that simple.

[image]

Source:

https://www.qt.io/

Comment: I want to use it for GPL/LGPL only. So it means i can use it unlimited right?

Comment: Sure your good to go!